# How do i execute a line one word at a time verticaly and execute a line one letter at a time horizontally in python?

Tags: python

So what the first part of my code does does is execute each word in the line but then goes on to do it 14 more times. I need it to execute the line one word at a time vertically only once. The second part I'll admit I didn't really have much progress on, it just prints the quote but I need it to print each letter at a time vertically.

```
Quote = "It was a bright cold day in April and the clocks were striking thirteen."

for letter in Quote:
   print Quote[0:2]
   print Quote[3:6]
   print Quote[7:8]
   print Quote[9:15]
   print Quote[16:20]
   print Quote[21:24]
   print Quote[25:27]
   print Quote[28:33]
   print Quote[34:37]
   print Quote[38:41]
   print Quote[42:48]
   print Quote[49:53]
   print Quote[54:62]
   print Quote[63:71]

print "-----"
print Quote
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `for letter in Quote` iterates through each character in `Quote`. For each iteration you're manually printing each word of `Quote`.

If you want to print each word of `Quote` then you could instead do:

```
for word in Quote.split():
    print word
```

Now you can print each letter of the word:

```
for word in Quote.split():
    print "Word: " + word
    for letter in word:
        print letter,
    print ""
```

Note the comma after `print letter,`. This makes so that no newline is added. You can also use `sys.stdout.write(letter)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this

```
for word in Quote.split():
    print word
```